# ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)

Tags: sql-server, django, docker, aws-lambda, unixodbc

I am trying to connect sql server 2019 (running on another server) with Django project in AWS Lambda environment (Amazon linux) but I am not able to establish connection between django and the sql server database and I get error `('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)`

**Below are the steps I am following to deploy to AWS lambda**

Spinning docker image with command:

```
docker run -t -i -p 8000:8000 -e AWS_PROFILE=zappa -v "/task" -v C:\Users\Ishan/.aws/:/root/.aws --rm zappa-docker-image
```

dockerfile

```
from lambci/lambda:build-python3.7

#make this default working directory
WORKDIR /task

#expose tcp port 8000 for debugging
EXPOSE 8000

#Prompt to remind you are in zappashell
RUN echo 'export PS1="\[\e[36m\]zappashell>\[\e[m\] "' >> /root/.bashrc

CMD ["bash"]
```

Once environment is up, I setup msodbcdriver17 using below commands taken from Microsoft's online setup guide:

```
RUN curl http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/Packages/unixODBC-2.3.1-14.el7.x86_64.rpm > /tmp/unixODBC-2.3.1-14.el7.x86_64.rpm
RUN yum -y install /tmp/unixODBC-2.3.1-14.el7.x86_64.rpm 
RUN curl http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/Packages/unixODBC-devel-2.3.1-14.el7.x86_64.rpm > /tmp/unixODBC-devel-2.3.1-14.el7.x86_64.rpm 
RUN yum -y install /tmp/unixODBC-devel-2.3.1-14.el7.x86_64.rpm
RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/rhel/7/prod.repo > /etc/yum.repos.d/mssql-release.repo
RUN ACCEPT_EULA=Y yum -y install msodbcsql17
```

Path of msodbcsql17 is `/opt/microsoft/`

Result of odbcinst -j

```
unixODBC 2.3.1
DRIVERS............: /etc/odbcinst.ini
SYSTEM DATA SOURCES: /etc/odbc.ini
FILE DATA SOURCES..: /etc/ODBCDataSources
USER DATA SOURCES..: /root/.odbc.ini
SQLULEN Size.......: 8
SQLLEN Size........: 8
SQLSETPOSIROW Size.: 8
```

Result of odbcinst.ini

```
[PostgreSQL]
Description=ODBC for PostgreSQL
Driver=/usr/lib/psqlodbcw.so
Setup=/usr/lib/libodbcpsqlS.so
Driver64=/usr/lib64/psqlodbcw.so
Setup64=/usr/lib64/libodbcpsqlS.so
FileUsage=1

[MySQL]
Description=ODBC for MySQL
Driver=/usr/lib/libmyodbc5.so
Setup=/usr/lib/libodbcmyS.so
Driver64=/usr/lib64/libmyodbc5.so
Setup64=/usr/lib64/libodbcmyS.so
FileUsage=1

[ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]
Description=Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server
Driver=/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql17/lib64/libmsodbcsql-17.10.so.1.1
UsageCount=1
```

Have used library `mssql-django==1.1.3` to build connection from django `Django==3.2.14`.

Server spins without issue but any request is served with below error:

```
[1662099546582] Internal Server Error: /dev/api/1.0/accounts/auth_token/
[1662099546582] Traceback (most recent call last):
[1662099546582] File "/var/task/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 219, in ensure_connection
[1662099546582] self.connect()
[1662099546582] File "/var/task/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 33, in inner
[1662099546582] return func(*args, **kwargs)
[1662099546582] File "/var/task/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 200, in connect
[1662099546582] self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
[1662099546582] File "/var/task/mssql/base.py", line 353, in get_new_connection
[1662099546582] conn = Database.connect(connstr, **args)
[1662099546582] pyodbc.Error: ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")
[1662099546582] The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
[1662099546582] Traceback (most recent call last):
[1662099546582] File "/var/task/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
[1662099546582] response = get_response(request)
[1662099546582] File "/var/task/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 181, in _get_response
[1662099546582] response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
[1662099546582] File "/var/task/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
[1662099546582] return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
[1662099546582] File "/var/task/django/views/generic/base.py", line 70, in view
[1662099546582] return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
[1662099546582] File "/var/task/rest_framework/views.py", line 509, in dispatch
[1662099546582] response = self.handle_exception(exc)
[1662099546582] File "/var/task/rest_framework/views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
[1662099546582] self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
[1662099546582] File "/var/task/rest_framework/views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
[1662099546582] raise exc
[1662099546582] File "/var/task/rest_framework/views.py", line 506, in dispatch
[1662099546582] response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
[1662099546582] File "/var/task/accounts/views.py", line 309, in post
[1662099546582] user = User.objects.get(email=email)
[1662099546582] File "/var/task/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
[1662099546582] return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
[1662099546582] File "/var/task/django/db/models/query.py", line 431, in get
[1662099546582] num = len(clone)
[1662099546582] File "/var/task/django/db/models/query.py", line 262, in __len__
[1662099546582] self._fetch_all()
[1662099546582] File "/var/task/django/db/models/query.py", line 1324, in _fetch_all
[1662099546582] self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
[1662099546582] File "/var/task/django/db/models/query.py", line 51, in __iter__
[1662099546582] results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)
[1662099546582] File "/var/task/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1162, in execute_sql
[1662099546582] sql, params = self.as_sql()
[1662099546582] File "/var/task/mssql/compiler.py", line 188, in as_sql
[1662099546582] supports_offset_clause = self.connection.sql_server_version >= 2012
[1662099546582] File "/var/task/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__
[1662099546582] res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
[1662099546582] File "/var/task/mssql/base.py", line 445, in sql_server_version
[1662099546582] with self.temporary_connection() as cursor:
[1662099546582] File "/var/lang/lib/python3.7/contextlib.py", line 112, in __enter__
[1662099546582] return next(self.gen)
[1662099546582] File "/var/task/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 603, in temporary_connection
[1662099546582] with self.cursor() as cursor:
[1662099546582] File "/var/task/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 33, in inner
[1662099546582] return func(*args, **kwargs)
[1662099546582] File "/var/task/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 259, in cursor
[1662099546582] return self._cursor()
[1662099546582] File "/var/task/mssql/base.py", line 246, in _cursor
[1662099546582] conn = super()._cursor()
[1662099546582] File "/var/task/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 235, in _cursor
[1662099546582] self.ensure_connection()
[1662099546582] File "/var/task/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 33, in inner
[1662099546582] return func(*args, **kwargs)
[1662099546582] File "/var/task/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 219, in ensure_connection
[1662099546582] self.connect()
[1662099546582] File "/var/task/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
[1662099546582] raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
[1662099546582] File "/var/task/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 219, in ensure_connection
[1662099546582] self.connect()
[1662099546582] File "/var/task/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 33, in inner
[1662099546582] return func(*args, **kwargs)
[1662099546582] File "/var/task/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 200, in connect
[1662099546582] self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
[1662099546582] File "/var/task/mssql/base.py", line 353, in get_new_connection
[1662099546582] conn = Database.connect(connstr, **args)
[1662099546582] django.db.utils.Error: ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")
```

**Can anyone suggest what could be the root cause and fix for it?**

EDIT:

cat /etc/os-release

```
NAME="Amazon Linux AMI"
VERSION="2018.03"
ID="amzn"
ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="2018.03"
PRETTY_NAME="Amazon Linux AMI 2018.03"
ANSI_COLOR="0;33"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:amazon:linux:2018.03:ga"
HOME_URL="http://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/"
VARIANT_ID="202011181029-al2018.03.426.0"
```

Comment: Is AWS Linux still based on CentOS 7? Please [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73579578/edit) your question to include the output of `cat /etc/os-release`?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I have added the details of cat /etc/os-release, Its "rhel fedora".

Comment: I'd encourage you to replace/upgrade that environment. Amazon Linux AMI 2018.03 was released on 2018-11-19 and [standard support was ended](https://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/) as of 2020-12-31. That particular AWS Linux was bundled with unixODBC-2.2.14 [packages](https://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/2018-03-packages/), so if you must continue using it then try to work with compatible package versions.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Updated to public.ecr.aws/sam/build-python3.9 image still the same error but at least this time I didn't had to install unixodbc, unixodbc-devel separately. > cat /etc/os-release > {NAME="Amazon Linux"
VERSION="2"
ID="amzn"
ID_LIKE="centos rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="2"
PRETTY_NAME="Amazon Linux 2"
ANSI_COLOR="0;33"
CPE_NAME="cpe:2.3:o:amazon:amazon_linux:2"
HOME_URL="https://amazonlinux.com/"
VARIANT_ID="202208261136-2.0.897.0"}

Comment: Are you importing Microsoft's repository signing key, https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc, anywhere? Ref: [Linux Software Repository for Microsoft Products # Package and Repository Signing Key](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/linux-package-repository-for-microsoft-software#package-and-repository-signing-key).

Comment: @AlwaysLearning  No, just installing the driver mentioned in post.

Comment: The `microsoft.asc` public key is part of the ODBC installation procedure for every other Linux in [Install the Microsoft ODBC driver for SQL Server (Linux)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server). I would count its absence against RHEL/CentOS on that page as an error, since the signature on the `msodbcsql17` package needs to be verified somehow for it to get installed successfully. It is mentioned for RHEL/CentOS on other Microsoft pages including the link in my previous comment.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I uninstalled `msodbcsql17` installed the `microsoft.asc` using the link you mentioned with same steps for RHEL/CENTOS 7 and reinstalled the driver but it didn't work.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Tried with EL8 as well and downloaded driver for this version but still no good.